# Socket remains connected after the remote computer closes it

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, tcp, .net-4.5

I've already searched but didn't solve my issue.
I'm simulating a TCP network on my localhost. Server listens on a port and client connects to the server. The problem is that when I close the socket by client, the `Socket.Connected` remains true in the server. I need to know when clients are disconnected.

I suppose when I call `Socket.Close` on client app, a TCP `FIN` packet is sent to the server, right? But it seems like it doesn't.

Can you give me a solution?

P.S. I already called shutdown before closing, but the problem still persists.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wahsac9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx mentions that you should call Shutdown() before closing.

Comment: This is why you will often find packets in a form `AreYouThere?` - `IAmHere`, which are doing no other job as to check what communications is still. Another way to detect disconnection is a timeout or exception during sending/receiving.

Comment: @Sinatr The pattern became famous with the Heartbleed bug. But I thought that it's important for crashes, kill -9 or, well, close without flush.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no notification based way to know if a client is disconnected. That is the nature of tcp/ip communication. The usual way to know if a client is connected or not is to write data to the client connection. If you get an error, you can guess that the client is disconnected. You can streamline the heuristics by looking for specific exceptions

Comment: Hm. I was under the impression that "no notification based way to know if a client is disconnected" is only true for crashes etc., but not for a regular shutdown (which the OP is trying to perform). Cf. http://www.tcpipguide.com/free/t_TCPConnectionTermination-2.htm for a sequence of events. In an orderly shutdown, the "notification based way to know if a client is disconnected" is receiving the FIN which is sent by the partner shutting down its connection. So I must assume that for one reason or another, a regular two-sided shutdown is not performed, for some reason or another.

Answer (score 1):

While I have no practical experience with socket programming in C# it seems that `Socket.Close()` does not send pending data and by implication doesn't send the FIN packet. (That is in my opinion a bit misleading because the `Close` semantics seem to differ from the `Stream.Close()` which calls `Dispose(true)` which tries to flush if possible. Correct me if I'm wrong.)

The [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wahsac9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) states:

> For connection-oriented protocols, it is recommended that you call
>   Shutdown before calling the Close method. This ensures that all data
>   is sent and received on the connected socket before it is closed.
>
> If you need to call Close without first calling Shutdown, you can
>   ensure that data queued for outgoing transmission will be sent by
>   setting the DontLingerSocket option to false and specifying a non-zero
>   time-out interval. Close will then block until this data is sent or
>   until the specified time-out expires. If you set DontLinger to false
>   and specify a zero time-out interval, Close releases the connection
>   and automatically discards outgoing queued data.

Comment: Oh :-) Bummer. I thought it was that easy.